# RSpec Git Bash Windows -- missing color?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, git-bash

I am using Git Bash on Windows for most of my Rails work and every time I run `bundle exec rspec spec` it alerts me "You must `gem install win32console` to use color on Windows," and then runs RSpec in plain black and white.  Yet I did install win32console, and when I run `gem list` on the list it has `win32console (1.3.0 x86-mingw32)`.  RSpec works fine, but I would love it to have some color.  I google searched this and found multiple solutions but none seem to work for me.  Can someone please write out a "step-by-step" approach to getting color with RSpec on Git Bash for Windows?

Comment: What solutions did you look at?

Comment: I don't remember -- random links on google, and none seemed to work.  I think I just typed in like "git bash windows rspec color" or something along those lines and then clicked a whole bunch of links on the first page of search results and found nothing that actually fixed the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but if you find a solution that works for you can you post it here?

Answer (score 4):

This blog is very good with showing how to do ansicon.
http://thehumblecto.blogspot.com/2012/06/rspec-color-output-in-windows.html

Comment: Awesome. This worked for me using Git Bash on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: This also works with Git Bash on Windows XP 32-bit. And according to the docs it also works with Windows 2000.

Comment: To clairfy... Git Bash runs `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`

If you put Ansicon on your path and change launcher to be `ansicon "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`  you get colours.   ALSO... you can install ansicon from "chocolatey" but remember to add it to your path!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Git Bash for Windows, but if it uses the standard Windows console you could try it with [*ANSICON*](http://adoxa.hostmyway.net/ansicon/).

You should visit the [ANSICON Homepage](http://adoxa.hostmyway.net/ansicon/) to find out about the latest version and download location.

It ships as a ZIP package containing sources and binaries. The installing instructions are in `readme.txt`.

Older downloads are still available on Github: https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads

Blog posts documenting ANSICON with screenshots are:

- [ANSI Command Line Colors under Windows](http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/)
- [RSpec Color Output in Windows](http://thehumblecto.blogspot.de/2012/06/rspec-color-output-in-windows.html)

Comment: Just take the right one with it's dll and drop it anywhere. Then when you're in that folder you can just double click it and run git or what ever is on your path. You get the escaped colors when ever you run tests that use them like rspec.

Comment: I'm not sure you even need .rspec with --color but try both to be sure. I'm having the same issue with this though for JRuby Shoes4 using rspec testing. Maybe it will work with the win32console gem. I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on @dallma77 post, using ansicon does seem to allow RSpec to output color to the Windows cmd prompt window!

I am now able to get color output from RSpec without copying the dll file (and quite probably without running 'ansicon -i' or 'ansicon -I' as well). Include an entry in your PATH pointing to the x64 folder (e.g. C:\Users\yourusername\pathtofolder\ansi150\x64) or x86 folder within where you extracted the ansicon zip file (I downloaded the zip file from here http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon/index.html).

But the trick seems to be that RSpec has to be run from the app root, otherwise I don't see the color output.

I'm following the (excellent) book Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), and 'sample_app' is my app root, so I see green and red color output with
e.g. C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec\requests\static_pages_spec.rb
but only monochrome output with
e.g. C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app\spec\requests>bundle exec rspec static_pages_spec.rb

Answer (score 1):

Since this is seemingly unanswered... Seeing this caused me to revisit this issue on my Win7 machine. I had not been able to get colors to work either, but since I had plenty else to worry about at the time (I was a RR nweb (still am, I guess) and Rspec was working in B/W) so I moved on. Seeing @Zetetic's reply reminded me that I had downloaded ANSICON but didn't connect the dots with it. So, I tried the following. I simply copied the ansi32.dll and ansicon.exe from the x86 folder of the ansi140 (extracted from the ansi140.zip) to my app's root folder. Opening a cmd window with Ruby and Rails and point to my app root and run ansicon.exe then run my test and I see green (and red).

I see it's been a while so I hope this helps sombody. I just became active here last week.

BTW, I do not have win32console in my gem list, but I do have win32-service 0.7.2 (unrelated I believe) and some other win32- gems. Don't remember how/what they are for, but here's the list:
win32-api 1.4.8,
win32-open3 0.3.2,
windows-api 0.4.1,
windows-pr 1.2.1.

Most likely, they are dependency gems for win32-service or other stuff that bundler included for me automatically. Wonderful thing that bundler. I think, however, win32-service is for mongrel-service (which I could not get to work, but that is another issue).

Comment: CL Kim has the ticket. Pointing the Path to ansi32.dll and ansicom.exe should make it work for all projects. IMO CL Kim's post is the answer to be accepted. Thanks.